# Computing a list of divisors of a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I developed the following Python functions when solving a few Project Euler problems, and since I'm not that familiar with Python, I'm curious at how I could improve them.

The code consists of a data holder class, and a few functions.

**Option class:**

This object stores data for a combination option. It has two data members:

- `value`: the value of the option
- `count`: how many times this option can be chosen

```
class Option:
    def __init__(self, value, count):
        self.value = value
        self.count = count
```

**Get Prime Factorization:**

This function calculates a number's prime factorization. It returns the factorization as a list of Options where the option's `value` is the prime and it's `count` is the power.

```
def getPrimeFactorization(n):
    f = []

    nth = 0

    while n > 1:
        prime = nthPrime(nth)

        if n % prime == 0:
            f.append(Option(prime, 1))

            n = n // prime

            while n % prime == 0:
                f[-1].count += 1

                n = n // prime

        nth += 1

    return f
```

**Get Combinations:**

To calculate the combinations, I use `getCombinationsIncrement` to iterate through each possible combination. The `index` is the index of the current option, `options` is the list of Options, and `chosen` is the number of times the Option will be chosen.

```
def getCombinationsIncrement(index, options, chosen):
    if index >= len(options):
        return False
    else:
        chosen[index] += 1

    if chosen[index] > options[index].count:
        chosen[index] = 0
        return getCombinationsIncrement(index + 1, options, chosen)
    else:
        return True
```

The `options` parameter is a list of options, `combine` is the function used to combine options, `base` is the base amount to combine with other values (it's similar to [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) if your familiar with JavaScript).

```
def getCombinations(options, combine, base):
    combos = [base]
    chosen = [0] * len(options)

    while getCombinationsIncrement(0, options, chosen):
        combos.append(base)

        for i in range(len(options)):
            for _ in range(chosen[i]):
                combos[-1] = combine(combos[-1], options[i].value)

    combos.sort()

    return combos
```

**Get Divisors**

Using the functions above it's easy to calculate all the divisors of a number.

```
def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y

def getDivisors(n):
    return getCombinations(getPrimeFactorization(n), multiply, 1)
```

---

My primary concern is with the `getCombinationsIncrement` function. I'd like it to be scoped only into the `getCombinations` function, and I don't particularly like having to make a class to fix that. It also might not be the best way to go about creating the combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is hard to understand. *Very* hard.

In Python we prefer iteration over recursion, not only does recursion limit you to a maximum depth of 1000 function calls, it also has severe performance impacts.

You should:

- Use `snake_case` in Python not `camelCase`. The only time you use `CamelCase` is when creating a class.
- Start using generators. In most cases you can just replace `list.append` with a `yield`.
- Change `nthPrime` to be a generator, say `primes`. As I'm not here to re-write `nthPrime` you can just use `itertools.count` to get an infinite generator.
- Don't duplicate logic before and during a loop. In `prime_factorization`, you wrote the floor division, `n //= prime`, twice.
- It's simpler to use a for loop and break from it, than `while` looping with a condition and manually taking the next item.
- You can use `collections.namedtuple` to remove the need to create your own class.

Merging the above together for just `prime_factorization` can get you:

```
from collections import namedtuple
from itertools import count

Option = namedtuple('Option', 'value count')


def primes():
    for i in count():
        yield nthPrime(i)


def prime_factorization(n):
    for prime in primes():
        count = 0
        while n % prime == 0:
            count += 1
            n //= prime
        if count:
            yield Option(prime, count)
        if n <= 1:
            break
```

After this you want to move more code into combinations, so that it's self contained in `getCombinationsIncrement`, and to rename it `combinations`.

- Change `combinations` to instead `yield` a `tuple` of `chosen`.
- Create `chosen` within `combinations`.
- Pass a single one dimensional list to `combinations` so that it's more usable later.
- When you finish running through all of `options` without `yield`ing, you want to stop. To do this you can use the `for ... else` syntax and just `break`.

This should be able to get you:

```
def combinations(options):
    chosen = [0] * len(options)
    while True:
        for i, option in enumerate(options):
            chosen[i] += 1
            if chosen[i] > option:
                chosen[i] = 0
                break
            yield tuple(chosen)
        else:
            break
```

Finally we want to change `combinations_reduce` to use `combinations`.

- First you should change `options` from a 2d lists to two 1d lists. You should want to get `values` and `counts` into their own lists. And so you can use `zip` with the argument unpacking operator, `*`, to expand the list to \$n\$ 2 long lists.
- You want to create `combos` off the bat, and can use `enumerate` to get the current index.

  Alternately you could try using `yield` instead, and off-load the sorting to the user.
- You can use `reduce` to replace your innermost loop.
- You can change the input to use default variables of `operators.mul` and `1`. This simplifies the usage, as you don't need to specify as much.

This can get you:

```
def combinations_reduced(options, combine=mul, base=1):
    values, counts = zip(*options)
    combos = [base] * len(counts)
    for i, chosen in enumerate(combinations(counts), 1):
        for j, value in enumerate(values):
            combos[i] = reduce(combine, [combos[i]] + [value] * chosen[j])
    combos.sort()
    return combos


def get_divisors(n):
    return combinations_reduced(prime_factorization(n))
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'm still getting used to Python, and I wrote the combinations code awhile ago. Looking forward to implement your recommendations.

Comment: @JoshDawson No problem. Just prioritize loops over recursion in Python and you'll be set, :)